# using Rietveld Code Review Tool for code review

Tags: python, git, github, rietveld

I pushed my branch `develop` for code review at [Rietveld Code Review Tool](https://codereview.appspot.com/repos) that got pushed successful using [jarodwen's](https://github.com/jarodwen/git-cl) `git-cl` and `upload.py`..

but that by default took the last commit. which I didn't wanted, as I wanted whole code to be reviewed, I created another branch `codeReview` and did an interactive rebase and had whole code in the last commit now when I am trying to `git-cl` upload to Rietveld Code Review Tool,

I am getting the following message..

```
$ git-cl upload origin/codeReview -r my@gmail.com,reviewer1@gmail.com,reviewer2@gmail.com,reviewer3@gmail.com,reviewer4@gmail.com --send-mail -m "Code review my python tool"
No output from ['git', 'diff', '--no-ext-diff', '--full-index', 'origin/codeReview', '-M']
```

And now neither the new issue is getting created nor pushed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the upload.py tool takes the branch or the patch that uses as the diff to be able to put to code review for the issue.

to do this we can uses `upload.py master -i <issueNumber>`

my current branch was codeReview and i did diff with master and put it to code review.